# How to remove the self-signed SSL certificate created in AWS ubuntu server

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, ssl, nginx

Hi I have deployed a simple flask python web in the AWS ubuntu server, followed this guys' e-book(https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-vii-error-handling). But I found there is issue, when I want to access the web by the browser. 
When I accessed the site in the chrome browser, there is security warning as shown in the figure. Although I can click the 'processed to...' to access successfully the site.

[image: issue]

But I don't want the warning image is shown when accessing the site.

I found that this issued is caused by the self-signed SSL certificate in AWS ubuntu server. The command for creating SSL certificate is following:

```
 ￼￼￼$ mkdir certs
 $ openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -days 365 -nodes -x509 \
  -keyout certs/key.pem -out certs/cert.pem
```

And the Nginx configuration is following, I want to delete or comment out the ssl_certificate part, and reload it. But I found that I can't access the site.
After I added ssl_certificate part, and it works. But there is still warning pages.
How to deal with this issue.

```
    server {
    # listen on port 443 (https)
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name _;
    # location of the self-signed SSL certificate
    ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/microblog2/certs/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/microblog2/certs/key.pem;

    location / {
        # forward application requests to the gunicorn server
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host \$host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP \$remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For \$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
    location /static {
        # handle static files directly, without forwarding to the application
        alias /home/ubuntu/microblog2/static;
        expires 30d;
} }
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to remove the cert from your setup, you need to return the config to port 80 with no SSL support. So remove `listen 443 ssl` `ssl_certificate` lines, and , replace with `listen 80` only.

Once you get a proper cert, you can return to this configuration, after you upload the cert files shown in the config.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have replaced the listen 443 ssl with listen 80. Although I can access the site. But sometimes when I click item of sites, it will be return to (https//180....).     and reload the page wrongly.